# What does an apostrophe before a word mean?

Tags: meaning, apostrophe

I am reading The Rifters Trilogy by Peter Watts and wonder, what does it mean, when the author sometimes uses words with an apostrophe before them? As I have figured, that is some sort of way of making the word special, but what way exactly?

For reference: the text is [available online for free](http://www.rifters.com/real/shorts.htm), I am talking about the third book in the trilogy, the "[Behemoth](http://www.rifters.com/real/Behemoth.htm)". If you search the page, you can easily find occurences of `'skin`, `'lawbreaker`, `'scaphe` and maybe several others.

**UPDATE**

As per the request, here are three use cases:

> Clarke turns her head sideways for a better view; the muscles in her neck tighten against the added drag. Erickson's flesh, exposed through the tear in his diveskin, is fish-belly white. It looks like gashed, bleeding plastic. His capped eyes look even deader than the flesh beneath his 'skin. He gibbers. His vocoder cobbles nonsense syllables together as best it can.
>   ...
>
> A comm panel decorates the bulkhead within easy reach. He taps it. "Ambient channel. Grace. How are you coming with those 'skins?"

-

> He dragged her to safety, to an evacuation 'scaphe hovering uncertainly over a station already emptied of personnel.

-

> But her friends had set their sights a lot higher than Achilles Desjardins; they were out to liberate every 'lawbreaker on the planet.
>   ...
>
> Sudbury's senior 'lawbreakers had worked between floors twenty and twenty-four. It had been lucky that Desjardins had managed to raise the alarm before they'd been hit.

Comment: Can you post a passage with an example to avoid link rot and for those of us who don't have access to those sites?

Comment: They're slang terms shortened from longer ones for commonly-used words. _'Scaphe_ has got to be a short version of _bathyscaphe_, for instance. And _'skin_ must be short for _diveskin_, a word used earlier.

Comment: @JohnLawler thought about that... but what about the `'lawbreaker` then?

Comment: _’lawbreaker_ seems to be a shortening of _natural law breaker_ or something like that; at least, the first mention of it (except for the title of the  prelude) is someone who can break the Second Law of Thermodynamics. There’s also _’lock_, _’phone_, _’scope_ (probably _periscope_ mentioned earlier in the sentence), _’fly_. These are all entirely idiosyncratic. They’re not established shortenings (except _’phone_, but it doesn’t seem to mean _telephone_ here). Impossible to know what they mean without reading the whole thing.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet oh, right.. that must be it! So, them are just shortened slang words.

Comment: Also, there are some more common ones: _’em_ (them), _’burbs_ (suburbs), _’scuse_ (excuse), _’round_ (around), etc. Those are standard and established shortenings that are found in actual speech in English.

Comment: If it's a science fiction novel, it's set in the future, and part of the fun is decoding the way (the author thinks) people will talk in the future. There are lots of examples one could point to, but the slang in _Clockwork Orange_ is one most people are familiar with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apostrophes are used to indicate dropped letters in a word. We are mostly familiar with them in contractions like *don't* and *isn't* but they can be used in other places too.

Once upon a time they were used to indicate shortening of words by omitting their initial part. It was once common to write *phone* (a shortening of *telephone*) as *'phone*. Another common use was *'bus* (short for *omnibus*). Both, of course, can now be used as words in their own right.

In your passage the author is attempting to convey that *'skins* and *'scaphe* are short forms of longer words. *'skin* is probably short for *diveskin*. *'scaphe* might well be short for *bathyscaphe*, but without knowing the work I can't say for sure.